# Problem in my javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The page URL has to change when the loadTest() function is called on a ahref click. But the page is getting refreshed only when alert is included in the code. If I remove the alert the same page is getting refreshed and not the new URL which I need.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadText(prod_id)
{
        curUrl = document.location.href.split("?");
        document.location = curUrl[0]+'?prodId='+prod_id;
    alert("Test");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `window.location` instead of `document.location`

```
function loadText(prod_id)
{
        curUrl = window.location.split("?");
        window.location = curUrl[0]+'?prodId='+prod_id;
}
```

Comment: @i2ijeya - see I updated your function.. Did u do the same? else can you paste the `html` from where u are calling the function?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location = curUrl[0]+'?prodId='+prod_id;
```